# lumen:IMAP library search with date is not working

Tags: php, laravel, imap, lumen

I am using below library in my composer.json file

```
"php-imap/php-imap": "3.0.*",
```

My code is below,

```
$folder['shortpath']="Inbox";
    new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{'.$mdata["server"].":993/imap/ssl}". $folder['shortpath'], $mdata["user"], $mdata["pass"], $dir);
                        $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox($mailbox, 'SINCE "01 December 2018"');
                        echo"<pre>";print_r($mailsIds);die;
```

It gives me empty array instead of value of UIDs

I have total 4 emails after 1st december

If I am using below code,

```
$mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox("ALL");
                            echo"<pre>";print_r($mailsIds);die;
```

then it gives me all emails till date in inbox

but date wise seach is not working

---

if I write below code then it gives error:

```
 $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('SINCE 01 December 2018');
```

ERROR:

```
IMAP method imap_search() failed with error: Unknown search criterion: SINCE 2018-12-06 09:32:32←
```

---

I found my solution as below , it is working for me,

I have userd

```
mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('SINCE "01 December 2018"');
```

but while open connection pass one more argument for "US-ASCII"

```
new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{'.$mdata["server"].":993/imap/ssl}".
                    $folder['shortpath'], $mdata["user"], $mdata["pass"], $dir, "US-ASCII");
```

---

But my another question is it is gives me list of new messages based on given date,

I required all update emails also like new mail, mark as unread, flagged , unflagged etc from given date. How to achive this??

Means how to identify new emails and any activity on existing emails till given date

Comment: Try following date format. `SINCE "01-Dec-2018"`

Comment: let me check it

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Does it give error or doesn't return any data? What exactly the date for those 4 emails you are expecting?

Comment: thanks for your help but I found my solution , I have update my question for that

Comment: But my another question , it is gives me list of new messages based on given date,

I required all update emails also like new mail, mark as unread, flagged , unflagged etc from given date. How to achive this??